# Splitting Mat into subMat of the same size

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm programming in C + + using Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV libraries, in version 2.4.6.

I would like to know how to divide a Mat object into n subMat of the same size. 
Let me explain better: I have a Mat of 12 rows and 24 columns. Suppose you want to divide it into 3 rows and 6 columns, thus obtaining 18 cells of 4 * 4. Each of these cells is a subMat of the initial Mat. I would like to know if there is a quick way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `colRange` and `rowRange`.

Something like this might help:

```
cv::Mat mat(12, 24, CV_8U);
cv::Mat imageBlock;
std::vector<cv::Mat> imageBlocks;
int blockSize = 4;
for(i = 0; i < 12; i += blockSize)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 24; j += blockSize)
    {
        imageBlock = mat.rowRange(i, i + blockSize).colRange(j, j + blockSize);
        imageBlocks.push_back(imageBlock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the iteration limits be `i < 12` and `j < 24`. I think you get one too few iterations in each loop. Also the end of a range is exclusive, so I think both instances of `blockSize - 1` should be simply `blockSize`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I've edited the post.. But I'm not sure about range being exclusive..

Comment: see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-rowrange : "endrow – An exclusive 0-based ending index of the row span."